# r programming subsetting a data frame multiple times for each value a vector and a data frame column

Tags: r

I have a vector with values 1:6, a data frame with 15 minute bins and a data frame of scan data. The data frames are shown below.

**bins**

```
idMin5Bin            BinStart              BinEnd
22        22 2015-08-13 10:15:00 2015-08-13 10:19:59
23        23 2015-08-13 10:20:00 2015-08-13 10:24:59
24        24 2015-08-13 10:25:00 2015-08-13 10:29:59
25        25 2015-08-13 10:30:00 2015-08-13 10:34:59
26        26 2015-08-13 10:35:00 2015-08-13 10:39:59
27        27 2015-08-13 10:40:00 2015-08-13 10:44:59
```

**cars**

```
  idTrip Link_IDLink StartCluster_id   Speed           firstScan
10     10           5              19  47.961 2015-08-13 10:11:49
11     11           5              14 118.800 2015-08-13 10:12:33
12     11           5              14 118.800 2015-08-13 10:13:16
13     12           5              22  47.793 2015-08-13 10:11:21
15     14           5              28  56.321 2015-08-13 10:13:09
24     22           5              52  45.692 2015-08-13 10:14:50
```

For each value in the vector, I want to reference the cars table to find all the cars that have a `LinkIDLink` value that matches the vector value.

I then want to subset all the matches by comparing the cars `FirstScan` with the bins table's `BinStart` and `BinEnd` table.

Finally, I want to graph the values in the subset.

The only strategy I can think of is using a nested loop (which I know is a no-no). Even with my nested loops, I get the following error from the sample code below.

```
for (i in 1:length(vector)){
  tempcars<-cars[cars[,2]==i,]
  for (k in 1:nrow(bins)){
    tempcars1<-subset(tempcars, firstScan<bins[k,3] & firstScan>bins[k,2])
    hist(tempcars1[,5], breaks =200)
}
}

    Error in hist.default(unclass(x), unclass(breaks), plot = FALSE, warn.unused = FALSE,  : 
  character(0) In addition: Warning messages:
1: In min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
2: In max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
```

I would certainly like to get away from using loops, but any help with the loop is appreciated.

Comment: Oh, is firstScan a time? You're probably getting NAs in tempcars1 because you're asking firstScan to be before the BinStart and after the BinEnd.

Comment: @ago no, there are no NAs. firstScan is a date stamp. I have made sure to convert all the date values to POSIXct as well

Comment: er, sorry, I think I confused your columns.

Comment: @ago, sorry, you are right, I have 0-length row.names as my data frame for tempcars1

Comment: So for each `Link_IDLink`, you want to identify the binID for each car?? Offhand I'd say the `foverlaps(...)` function in the data.table package is the most efficient way to do this.

Comment: If you repost your data using the output of `dput(bins)` and `dput(cars)`, I'll take a look at it (that is unless someone else answers first...).

Comment: you could use an approach like this:

Comment: use split to split the data into a list based on the values of your vector - so something like `df <- cars [ cars$Link_IDLink %in% 1:6, ]; split(cars, cars$Link_IDLink)`

Comment: then use write a function that takes BinStart and BinEnd inputs and subsets data between those bins. you could then lapply to your overall list a function that uses mapply to split the list into binned data. you'd ended up with a 2 level list: level 1 would split based on vector, level 2 split based on binned data

Comment: actually you can use cut.POSIXt .. I'll whip up an example

Answer (score 0):

here's an answer to the start of this ... hope it helps ...

```
# Generate the data
theVec <- 1:6
someTimes <- seq(as.POSIXlt(Sys.time()), by = "sec", length = 300)
bins <- data.frame(idMin5Bin = 1:20, BinStart = someTimes[1+(15*(0:19))], BinEnd = someTimes[(15*(1:20))])
cars <- data.frame(Link_IDLink = rep(theVec, each = 20), 
  firstScan = sample(someTimes, 120, replace = T), Speed = runif(120, 30, 100))


# First split by Link_IDLink
subCars <- subset(cars, Link_IDLink %in% theVec)
carList <- split(subCars, subCars$Link_IDLink)

# Now "cut" the times for each element of the list
outList <- lapply(carList, function(df, binData) {
  theBins <- c(binData$BinStart, binData$BinEnd [ nrow(binData)] )
  df$idMin5Bin <- cut(df$firstScan, theBins, labels = binData$idMin5Bin )
  df
}, binData = bins)
```

Ends up with this ...

```
> head(outList[[1]])
  Link_IDLink           firstScan    Speed isMin5Bin
1           1 2015-09-10 22:42:33 33.85446        17
2           1 2015-09-10 22:41:06 81.43807        11
3           1 2015-09-10 22:40:53 90.59927        10
4           1 2015-09-10 22:39:38 56.89429         5
5           1 2015-09-10 22:40:20 70.44760         8
6           1 2015-09-10 22:42:08 88.93505        15
```

You could plot that in a range of ways - let me know if you want help with that bit.